# Sputtering when eccelerating from a stop

Tags: troubleshooting

I have 98 Volvo V70 awd I have been experiencing  sputtering, when I accelerate from a stop, and sometimes as I slow down. I changed the Mass Flow sensor, added fuel injector cleaner, and car seem to drive fine. Once it heated up and I came to a stop, the sputtering began again. I turned my car off waited about ten minutes, started it back up, and drove it home. I have purchased a fuel filter and pump and plan on checking injectors in the morning. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the spark plugs?

Comment: Have you done a full service lately? or when was it last serviced? Air filter?